# Eliminate horizontal scrolling in div in favor of horizontal scrolling in browser window

Tags: css, xhtml, html

I have a div, set to 800px wide, that will automatically scroll horizontally if the browser window is resized to < 800px. The behavior I would like, is to have the browser window scroll instead of the div. It would seem simple but for some reason I'm getting hung up on it. Any ideas?

The page in question:
http://www.caseyflynn.com/game/

The div CSS:

```
div#main_container {
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    width:800px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The BODY CSS:

```
html, body {
    background-color:#000;
    border:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size : 62.5%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

I'm assuming anyone looking at this will have the ability to see the HTML and the CSS. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to have the body have an added scrollbar to scroll through all the content on your page, instead of having your div have a scrollbar added? If that's the case, it already does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I removed both overflow attributes and included an empty div after my floated content with a clear:both property. This caused the browser window to scroll rather than my div and my div to expand around my floated content.

Solution found here:
http://ask.metafilter.com/134982/How-can-I-make-a-div-expand-vertically-to-fit-its-floated-content

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting out `overflow: auto;` in the body css.

Answer (score 0):

Remove both overflow attributes, the `overflow:hidden` from the div and especially the `overflow:auto` from the HTML element. Then it will do what you want.

Comment: unfortunately, when I do that the div does not expand to include the content of the box for some reason. I have a table, which contains a form, that's floated to the right. I've tried clear:both on that table element but that doesn't achieve the intended result.